# How to edit variable globally python

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, scope

I am working on a python library. I have a function, `moveTrack(fileorvar, track_code, x, y)`.
Right now I have the `track_code`, `x`, and `y` arguments working. What `fileorvar` does is it decides if you are editing a variable or a file, in which case the function will have to open said file. I am doing this in this way:

```py
def moveTrack(self, fov, track_code, x-coord, y-coord):
    print((lambda c,n,x,y,l:'#'.join([','.join([(lambda o:' '.join([(lambda m:(lambda p,v:'0'if p==0else(('-'if v else'')+''.join([n[((p//(32**q))%32)]for q in range(int(l.log(p,32))+1)][::-1])))(abs(m),(m<0)))(int(m,32)+x if(t!=2and j%2==0)or(t==2and j%2==1)else int(m,32)+y)if(t!=2or j!=0)else m for j,m in enumerate(o)if m!='']))(i.split(' '))for i in d])for t,d in enumerate(c)]))([a.split(',')for a in track_code.split('#')],list('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'),int(x-coord),int(y-coord),__import__('math')))
```

The `self` argument is necessary but not used at all by the user. I want to have an if/else statment inside of it like this:

```py
def moveTrack(self, fov, track, x-coord, y-coord):

    if fov == 'f':
        track_code = open(track_code, 'r')
    else:
        track_code = str(track)

    print((lambda c,n,x,y,l:'#'.join([','.join([(lambda o:' '.join([(lambda m:(lambda p,v:'0'if p==0else(('-'if v else'')+''.join([n[((p//(32**q))%32)]for q in range(int(l.log(p,32))+1)][::-1])))(abs(m),(m<0)))(int(m,32)+x if(t!=2and j%2==0)or(t==2and j%2==1)else int(m,32)+y)if(t!=2or j!=0)else m for j,m in enumerate(o)if m!='']))(i.split(' '))for i in d])for t,d in enumerate(c)]))([a.split(',')for a in track_code.split('#')],list('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'),int(x-coord),int(y-coord),__import__('math')))
```

This will not work. this is because when I edit track_code, it only saves inside that function. I know I can fix this by putting the one-liner inside of each of the if/else statements. I would, however, like to avoid this to improve readability.

EDIT

What I have now is this:

```py
def moveTrack(self, fov, track, x-coord, y-coord):

        track_code = None

        if fov == 'f':
            global track_code
        track_code = open(track, 'r')
            else:
        global track_code
            track_code = track


        print((lambda c,n,x,y,l:'#'.join([','.join([(lambda o:' '.join([(lambda m:(lambda p,v:'0'if p==0else(('-'if v else'')+''.join([n[((p//(32**q))%32)]for q in range(int(l.log(p,32))+1)][::-1])))(abs(m),(m<0)))(int(m,32)+x if(t!=2and j%2==0)or(t==2and j%2==1)else int(m,32)+y)if(t!=2or j!=0)else m for j,m in enumerate(o)if m!='']))(i.split(' '))for i in d])for t,d in enumerate(c)]))([a.split(',')for a in track_code.split('#')],list('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv'),int(x-coord),int(y-coord),__import__('math')))
```

But when I try to import the library it throws this error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\frhd\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from frhd import Track, Encode, Decode, Loader
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\frhd\Track.py", line 14
    global track_code
    ^
SyntaxError: name 'track_code' is assigned to before global declaration
```

WHYYYYYY?

Comment: If you really want to improve readability, get rid of this monstruosity of a one-liner...

Comment: Also, depending on `fov`, `track_code` will either be a string, or a file object. Did you mean to `read()` it?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille haha yep. I am going to, but the original is something like 500 lines and a TERROR to make pep8 compatible. Meaning that it would take me upwards of an hour and it crashes pep8 converters. I was messing around with it for about an hour last night before I just gave up. I will eventually, but not now. Keeping it outside of the statement just made my life easier when I do fix it.

Comment: Do I have to (use read())? I figure that if I just declare it as a file than it will work.

Comment: Good luck... ;)  A file and a string are different, you can't manipulate one like the other. Iterating on a text file iterates on the lines, doing it on a string iterates on the chars. `in` tells you if a line is in the file, and read it up to this point - if you try again, it will start from where it left, or from the end of the file if it didn't match the previous time. `in` will tell you if a string is a substring of another, when applied to a string. Many operations will only be valid on one of the objects. So, you probably want to `read()` the file content, this will give you a string.

Comment: I did it now :)

Comment: wait, do I have to put the read() in the one-liner or in the if/else?

Comment: After your if/else block, you want to have a string, however you got it. So yes, put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify global variable by declaring it with keywork 'global' inside a function.

```
track_code = None

def moveTrack(self, fov, track, x-coord, y-coord):

   global track_code
   # Now changing track_code will update global variable
   track_code = 'something'
```